# Migrate hierarchical SQL Server data to Azure CosmosDB

Tags: sql-server, azure-cosmosdb

I am exploring options to migrate data from SQL Server 2016 into CosmosDB with SQL API. Source data is relational. I need to join them and migrate to CosmosDB db in such a way that each row is migrated as a document. Here is an example.

[image: Source Tables]

I want to migrate these individual Product table rows combining it’s related ProductSubCatalog table row something like below document.

```
{              
          "ProductID": 970,                         
          "Name": "Touring-2000 Blue, 46",                         
          "ProductNumber": "BK-T44U-46",                         
          "MakeFlag": true,                         
          "FinishedGoodsFlag": true,                       
          "Color": "Blue",                                                       
          "ModifiedDate": "2014-02-08T10:01:36.827",                   
          "ProductSubCatalog": {                
                       "ProductSubcategoryID": 3,                      
                       "Name": "Touring Bikes"                                                                                 
          }                          
}
```

I tried [DocumentDB Data Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) with Source as “SQL” with below query.

```
SELECT 
    [ProductID],P.[Name], [ProductNumber], [MakeFlag],  
    [FinishedGoodsFlag], [Color], [SafetyStockLevel], [ReorderPoint], 
    [StandardCost], [ListPrice],
    Ps.ProductSubcategoryID AS 'ProductSubCatalog.ProductSubcategoryID', 
    Ps.Name AS 'ProductSubCatalog.Name'   
FROM
    [Production].[Product] P 
LEFT JOIN
    Production.ProductSubcategory PS ON P.ProductSubcategoryID = ps.ProductSubcategoryID
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Product')
```

As the above query generates single JSON data for all rows in Product table, DocumentDB Data Migration Tool imports it as single document. Does someone know other options to achieve this without writing custom application to query to SQL Server data, form JSON document and import it? Any suggestions and pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: There is a different alternative if this isn't working for you and that's what i actually did. You can create a simple .net core app that follows an EF Core, DB first approach. Then simply retrieve everything in batches using DTOs and add them in CosmosDB. You can do that by using [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) which will pick up your objects and add them in cosmosdb.
Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Cosmonaut

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I just followed [Import from SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQL) and based on your tables to check this issue.

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You do not need to add `FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Product')` within your query.

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. It works for data with one-to-one relationship, not for data with one-to-many relationship. I went ahead and modified source code of that data migration tool from [git hub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool) to convert JSON string data (retrieved by my above SQL query) as C# JObject instead of key-value pair object as it was originally doing. It worked for my requirement.

Comment: You'd better post your own answer with the solution for other people who may encounter the similar issue.